# Extract and replace images form a PDF file

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf, images

I'm interested in finding a way (from command line only, in Linux) to extract images from PDF files, apply some effects and then put the new images back inside the PDF file.

While I found a way to extract images from a PDF file and I can apply visual effects to it
I couldn't find a way to replace the original images inside PDF with the changed images.

Is there a way to do this in Linux?

Comment: To extract images (but not replace them) you can use `pdfimages`; for replacing, I found this link [How to replace images in a PDF? | RubyPDF Blog](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2007/12/12/how-to-replace-images-in-a-pdf/), which has Java and C# code, but I'm not sure if it uses a specific library or something....

Comment: duplicate of [Replace an image in a PDF using command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208232/replace-an-image-in-a-pdf-using-command-line)